# clear checkbox when repeating a todo task

Tags: org-mode

Let's say you have a repeated task with subtasks using checkboxes like:

```
  * TODO [2/2] Task
    DEADLINE: <2021-09-07 ++1y>
   + [x] done
   + [x] also done
```

When I mark the Task as DONE? I'd like the chekboxes to be unchecked as the DEADLINE is incremented one year and the TODO State switches back to TODO.

I couldn't find a variable for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that there is [org-checklist](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-checklist.html) which takes care of clearing the checkboxes, using
the `RESET_CHECK_BOXES` property.

`org-checklist` used to be in the `contrib/` directory that was bundled with Org mode, but all of the `contrib/` stuff has now been moved to its [own separate repo](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib).

Answer (score 2):

There is `org-todo-repeat-hook` which is run when an item is repeated, so you can add a function that clears the checkboxes to it. Org mode offers such a function for a subtree, `org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree`, which should work fine for the simple case of a one-level subtree:

```el
(add-hook 'org-todo-repeat-hook #'org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree)
```

If this is too blunt an instrument (it will reset *any* task's checkboxes in *any* level of the subtree whenever the task is repeated), then you can wrap the `org-reset-checkbox-state-subtree` in a function that conditionally calls it, e.g. by checking that the task is the one you want. But as a first approximation it should work fine.

BTW, untested.